# sscanf not parsing string properly

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "johnsmith@yahoo.com, 22:44:45";
    char user[45], email[45];
    int h, m, s;
    sscanf(str, "%44s@%44s, %d:%d:%d", user, email, &h, &m, &s);
    printf("User: %s | Email: %s | Hour: %d | Minutes: %d | Seconds: %d\n", user, email, h, m, s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:  `User: johnsmith@yahoo.com, | Email: garbage | Hour: garbage | Minutes: garbage | Seconds: garbage`
Why is it storing everything up to , into user?

Comment: Why not? What did yo expect it to do? `%s` will read all characters up to the next white space.

Comment: `%44s` means to read until whitespace or 44 characters, whichever comes first.

Comment: `scanf()` isn't a pattern matching function. Putting `@` after `%44s` doesn't mean to stop when it gets to to `@`.

Comment: @kaylum I thought it would store johnsmith into user, yahoo.com into email, h: 22, m: 44, s: 45. I must've misunderstood how sscanf works. I thought I could provide the format of the string and it would get parsed accordingly

Comment: maybe take a look at strtok() instead.

Comment: You should check the return value from `sscanf` -- if it is not 5, then something went wrong with the input string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%44s@` doesn't stop reading the string when it gets to the `@` character. It means to read a string until whitespace, up to 44 characters. Then it needs to read a `@` character after that in order to continue parsing the rest of the string.

To read characters up to `@`, use `%44[^@]`. Then follow this with `@` to skip over that character before extracting the next string.

```
    sscanf(str, "%44[^@]@%44[^,], %d:%d:%d", user, email, &h, &m, &s);
```

Comment: Alternately, use something like `%44[-_a-zA-Z0-9.]` to only allow those characters in the name and address.  Also ALWAYS check the return value from scanf